# Conformal Ricci Scalar computation in Baumgarte's Ex. 3.3

Tags: general-relativity

I'm asked to show that contracting indices of this Ricci Tensor:
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\ogamma}{\overline{\gamma}}
\newcommand{\OGamma}{\overline{\Gamma}}
\newcommand{\OD}{\overline{D}}
R_{ij} = & \; \overline{R}_{ij} -2 \left( \OD_i \OD_j \ln \psi + \ogamma_{ij} \OD^2 \ln \psi \right) \notag \\
  & + 4 \left(
  \left( \OD_i \ln \psi \right) \left( \OD_j \ln \psi \right) - \ogamma_{ij} \ogamma^{kl} \left( \OD_k \ln \psi \right)
  \left( \OD_l \ln \psi \right) \right).
\end{align}
using the metric $\gamma^{ij} = \psi^{-4} \ogamma^{ij}$, where $\psi$ is a function of a spatial slice (in 3+1 decomposition).

My solution is:
\begin{align}
R = & \; \gamma^{ij} R_{ij} = \psi^{-4} \ogamma^{ij} R_{ij} \\
= & \; \psi^{-4} \ogamma^{ij} \left(
 \overline{R}_{ij} -2 \left( \OD_i \OD_j \alpha + \ogamma_{ij} \OD^2 \alpha \right) + 4 \left(
  \OD_i \alpha \OD_j \alpha - \ogamma_{ij} \ogamma^{kl} \OD_k \alpha \OD_l \alpha \right) \right) \\
= &\; \psi^{-4} \left( \overline{R} - 2 \left( 1 + \ogamma^{ij} \ogamma_{ij} \right) \OD^2 \alpha +
  4 \left(1 - \ogamma^{ij} \ogamma_{ij} \right) \ogamma^{kl} \OD_k \alpha \OD_l \alpha \right) \\
= &\; \psi^{-4} \left( \overline{R} - 8 \OD^2 \alpha - 8 \ogamma^{kl} \OD_k \alpha \OD_l \alpha \right) \\
= &\; \psi^{-4} \overline{R} - 8 \psi^{-5} \OD^2 \psi - \underbrace{8 \psi^{-6} \ogamma^{kl} \OD_k \psi \OD_l \psi}_
  {\text{this should not be here}},
\end{align}
but the last term is absent in the book.

What did I miss?

---

($\gamma_{ij}$ is a 3-dimensional metric tensor so $\gamma_{ij} \gamma^{ij} = 3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied the derivative incorrectly for:
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\OD}{\overline{D}}
\OD^2 \alpha = \OD^2 \ln \psi
\end{align}

The correct expression is:
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\ogamma}{\overline{\gamma}}
\newcommand{\OD}{\overline{D}}
\ogamma^{kl} \left( -\psi^{-2} \OD_k \psi \OD_l \psi + \psi^{-1} \OD_k \OD_l \psi \right)
\end{align}
which trivially cancels the term in the question.